# How to convert an array's values into distinct keys within each entry with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, for-loop

I have the following dataset. Each entry in the array has a key called 'Type,' and there are three types.

```
var data = [
        {date: "12/27/2012", Type: "http_200", Val: 190, Irrelevant: "Stringa"},
        {date: "12/28/2012", Type: "http_200", Val: 10, Irrelevant: "Stringb"},
        {date: "12/29/2012", Type: "http_404", Val: 100, Irrelevant: "Stringc"},
        {date: "12/30/2012", Type: "http_302", Val: 90, Irrelevant: "Stringd"},
        ];
```

I'd like each of the types to become its own key with the value as the same as the value of 'Val'

```
Result = [
        {date: "12/27/2012",Type: "http_200", Val: 190, http_404: 0, http_200: 190, http_302: 0},
        {date: "12/28/2012",Type: "http_200", Val: 10, http_404: 0, http_200: 10, http_302: 0},
        {date: "12/29/2012",Type: "http_404",Val: 100, http_404: 100, http_200: 0, http_302: 0},
        {date: "12/30/2012",Type: "http_302",Val: 90, http_404: 0, http_200: 0, http_302: 90},
        ];
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this? I'll be performing this on a very larger data set.

Also, would it be possible to do this without knowing all the types, so that I can run it on any given key with ease.

I can try something like the following, but the issue is that it is incredibly tedious to do this for each key and value considering the amount of data and types

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
    if(d.Type = 'http_200'){d.http_200=d.Val, d.http_404=0, http_302=0} else {d.http_200=d.0, d.http_404=0, http_302=0};
    if(d.Type = 'http_404'){d.http_200=0, d.http_404=d.Val, http_302=0} else {d.http_200=d.0, d.http_404=0, http_302=0};
    if(d.Type = 'http_302'){d.http_200=0, d.http_404=0, http_302=d.Val} else {d.http_200=d.0, d.http_404=0, http_302=0};
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to read the `Type` and `Val` properties? Do you know how to use a variable as the name of a property? Where specifically is the issue?

Comment: ...and where is the data coming from? Is this originating as JSON, or are the objects constructed in your JavaScript code?

Comment: Most efficient will be using `Array.prototype.map()` to *transform* the array of objects to the preferred form. It will be impossible to do it in one pass without knowing all the possible types.

Comment: @techfoobar: I'd bet a simple `for` loop is more efficient. It actually could be done in one pass if the objects inherit from a constructor's prototype. Like: `if (!(obj.Type in obj)) {Foo.prototype[obj.Type] = 0;}`. Though knowing them beforehand would be better.

Comment: @techfoobar Usually loops are faster than ES5 array methods. But IMO array methods are cooler and cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll ned to loop through the array twice. First to extract all the types, then to create the values.

```
var data = [
    {date: "12/27/2012", Type: "http_200", Val: 190, Irrelevant: "Stringa"},
    {date: "12/28/2012", Type: "http_200", Val: 10, Irrelevant: "Stringb"},
    {date: "12/29/2012", Type: "http_404", Val: 100, Irrelevant: "Stringc"},
    {date: "12/30/2012", Type: "http_302", Val: 90, Irrelevant: "Stringd"},
];
var types = [];

function getTypes(data){
    for (var i = 0, endi = data.length; i<endi; ++i){
        var obj = data[i]
        if(types.indexOf(obj.Type)) types.push(obj.Type);
    }
}

function addAllTypesToData(data, types){
    for (var data_i = 0, data_endi = data.length; data_i<data_endi; ++data_i){
        var obj = data[data_i];
        for (var type_i = 0, type_endi = types.length; type_i<type_endi; ++type_i){
            obj[types[type_i]] = (obj.Type === types[type_i]) ? obj.Val : 0;
        }
    }
}

getTypes(data);
addAllTypesToData(data, types);
```